# proving differentiability at (0,0)

Tags: derivatives

Let F(x,y) be a a two variables function that is continuous in R^2 and differentiable at R^2/({0/0}.

Its partial derviatives(Fx(x,y),Fy(x,y)) at (0,0) both approach zero.
I have to prove that the function is differentiable at (0,0).

Which direction should I go ? Should I try proving it using differentiability definition or somehow prove partial derivatives are continuous ?

Comment: "continuous on the entire real line" you mean continuous on $\mathbb R^2$ right?

Comment: Yes, Sorry about the misunderstanding. fixed it.

Comment: I will edit your question with MathJax. See how I do it, next time you can do it.

Comment: Here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr)